# Extended Complex Plane and the Point at Infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have a function on the extended complex plane given by
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{1-|z|}.$$
Here anywhere on $|z|=1$, the function maps that point to infinity.

In the above example, if we take some $z$ satisfying $|z|=1$, when this point is mapped to infinity, does it have some angle for which it is mapped with respect to the positive real axis? Or will this point at infinity always lie on the real line? I feel as though it may be the former, where the point of infinity is fully determined by the angle $z$ (On the numerator) makes with the positive real axis.

On the open unit disk, we know that the function is a bijection, and
$$f^{-1}(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|}.$$
How may we be able to discuss the inverse of infinity for this inverse? If we were to use this function, we would only ever obtain a real number as the inverse of infinity, however we expect the inverse to be all points lying on the unit circle. Perhaps I should be considering the map of the circle to a circle at infinity? And consider the inverse of this?

I hope someone can correct my understanding!

Comment: It is  a bijection from the open unit disk to the complex plane. It is not even  defined on the 'normal complex plane'.

Comment: My bad @KaviRamaMurthy. I hope my edits make the question better.

Comment: There is only one infinity in the extended complex plane. The map is not one-to-one on the  extended complex plane.

Comment: So we can’t find the inverse of infinity in this case @KaviRamaMurthy